# What is a "man of knowledge"?

Tags: nikah, sayyid

I have read that it is normally expected and allowed that a man may marry a sayyidah only if he is also a sayyid, or if he is a "man of knowledge", but the sayyidah is not. What does this mean, a "man of knowledge"?

Answer (score 1):

It means a scholar or jurist of Islam, who is recognized and respected by the Muslims. This is a quality which elevates his status and is considered by some to offset the inequality of lineage between the spouses.

**Ref:**

> والعالم يكون كفئا للعلوية
>
> <sup>— [Muheet al-Burhaani](https://shamela.ws/book/10875/1017)</sup>

> أن الفقيه يكون كفئا للعلوية
>
> <sup>— [Fataawa al-Alamgiriyyah](https://shamela.ws/book/21640/289)</sup>

Comment: What is the Arabic word for this kind of man, if you don't mind me asking?